# Java Serialization of PrintService Attributes

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization

From my search, I think [this](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6278300) is a pretty good summary of my problem. Perhaps, I'm serializing or de-serializing the objects wrong? Or if the serialization is correct, is there a fix/workaround to my issue?

I've been using [this](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/sun/print/Win32PrintService.java.html) as reference to the `Win32MediaSize` class. I've got another slightly related question regarding the referenced `Win32MediaSize` class. See the code that begins at 1640 which is the static initializer. I tried to reproduce that so I could see execution order:

```
public clsss Why {
  
  static {
    String a = "Hello";
  }
  
  public class Not {
    static { // gives me a Cannot define static initializer in inner type error
      String b = "World";
    }
  }
}
```

This isn't the main issue but it would be great if someone could shed some light here. I personally believe its the problem in `Win32MediaSize` but I don't know why. I also tried what they did on line 85 and double brackets and neither works. Removing the keyword `static` does resolve the error but I think that produces different behavior per my understanding.

The basic problem is that I need to execute `getSupportedAttributeValues` for each PrintService in order to read in serialized data which defeats the purpose of serializing the data. The reason for serializing the data is because `getSupportedAttributeValues` takes too long to finish (40+ seconds).

Here's the exception (the `value` and `range` varies depending on far along the `PrintService` has loaded - in the actual program it's loading in another thread; see [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/26484/improve-my-threading-in-java) for reference):

```
java.io.InvalidObjectException: Integer value = 124 not in valid range 0..3for class class sun.print.Win32MediaSize
    at javax.print.attribute.EnumSyntax.readResolve(EnumSyntax.java:184)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadResolve(ObjectStreamClass.java:1056)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1761)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1328)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(ObjectInputStream.java:1666)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1322)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:350)
    at java.util.HashMap.readObject(HashMap.java:1030)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:969)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1848)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1752)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1328)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:350)
    at com.iii.print.PrintServiceLoader.readCachedData(PrintServiceLoader.java:355)
    at com.iii.print.PrintServiceLoader.main(PrintServiceLoader.java:420)
```

Here's the relevant code bits:

Methods `works()` and `fails()` is what I'm having issues with.

```
void works() {
  HashMap<String, Object> m = null;
  HashMap<String, Object> mpa = null;
  doLookup(); // this is what causes the following call to not fail
  m = readCachedData( "a" );
  mpa = readCachedData( "b" );
}

void fails() {
  /* Assuming the files have already been created */
  HashMap<String, Object> m = null;
  HashMap<String, Object> mpa = null;
  m = readCachedData( "a" ); // this fails (see exception)
  mpa = readCachedData( "b" ); // this will work just fine
}
  

void doLookup() {
  PrintService[] psList = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices( DocFlavor.SERVICE_FORMATTED.PRINTABLE, null );

  HashMap<String, Object> cachedMedia = new HashMap<String, Object>();
  HashMap<String, Object> cachedMediaPrintableArea = new HashMap<String, Object>();
  for ( PrintService ps : psList ) {
    Object media = ps.getSupportedAttributeValues( Media.class, null, null );
    Object mediaPrintableArea = ps.getSupportedAttributeValues( MediaPrintableArea.class, null, null );
    cachedMedia.put( ps.getName(), media );
    cachedMediaPrintableArea.put( ps.getName(), mediaPrintableArea );
  }
  
  writeCachedData( "a", cachedMedia );
  writeCachedData( "b", cachedMediaPrintableArea );
}

boolean writeCachedData( String filename, Map<String, Object> data ) {
  boolean successful = true;

  if ( filename != null && !filename.isEmpty() && data != null && !data.isEmpty() ) {
    FileOutputStream fileOutStream = null;
    ObjectOutputStream objOutStream = null;

    try {
      fileOutStream = new FileOutputStream( filename );
      objOutStream = new ObjectOutputStream( fileOutStream );
      objOutStream.writeObject( data );
    } catch ( FileNotFoundException e ) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      successful = false;
    } catch ( IOException e ) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      successful = false;
    } finally {
      try {
        if ( objOutStream != null ) {
          objOutStream.close();
        }
      } catch ( IOException e ) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        successful = false;
      }
      try {
        if ( fileOutStream != null ) {
          fileOutStream.close();
        }
      } catch ( IOException e ) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        successful = false;
      }
    }

  } else {
    successful = false;
  }

  return successful;
}

Map<String, Object> readCachedData( String filename ) {
  Map<String, Object> cachedData = null;

  if ( filename != null && !filename.isEmpty() ) {
    File f = new File( ".", filename );
    if ( f.exists() ) {
      FileInputStream fileInStream = null;
      ObjectInputStream objInStream = null;

      try {
        fileInStream = new FileInputStream( f );
        objInStream = new ObjectInputStream( fileInStream );
        cachedData = (Map<String, Object>) objInStream.readObject();
      } catch ( FileNotFoundException e ) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      } catch ( IOException e ) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      } catch ( ClassNotFoundException e ) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      } finally {
        try {
          if ( fileInStream != null ) {
            fileInStream.close();
          }
        } catch ( IOException e ) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
          if ( objInStream != null ) {
            objInStream.close();
          }
        } catch ( IOException e ) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
    }
  }

  return cachedData;
}
```

As you can tell, I'm on Windows 7 x64 and using jdk 1.6.0_31. Let me know if I left out relevant information.

Answer (score 1):

Concerning your first problem:

class Not should be public static, not public.

```
public class Test {

    static {

    }

    public static class Not {
        static { 
            String b = "World";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 Yes, I thought I tried this but OK this does solve that particular error. However, if you look at `Win32MediaSize` (2nd paragraph) it's not static.